# How to convert this into postgresql stored procedures in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I want to change the postgresql queries to stored procedures in Nodejs.

```
app.post("/add", async(req, res) => {
try {
    const { name, email, hobby } = req.body;
    const newStudent = await pool.query("INSERT INTO student (name, email, hobby) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *", [name, email, hobby]);
    res.json(newStudent.rows);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
}
```

})

Comment: As you want to return the generated values, you need a function. Procedures aren't meant to return something.

Comment: A *stored procedure* is a hunk of code that lives in a relational database server. You can invoke it from a host language like nodejs (or Java, or whatever) with [CALL procedure (arg, arg);](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- Create a stored procedure to insert a new student

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_student (name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR, hobby VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE(id INT, name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR, hobby VARCHAR)
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO student (name, email, hobby) VALUES (name, email, hobby) RETURNING *;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM student;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
-- Execute the stored procedure to add a new student

SELECT add_student('John Doe', 'john@example.com', 'Gardening');
```

Comment: Your function will return the content of the entire table `student` each time you call it.

Comment: @NeutroLink you can format code by putting it between two lines containing only three backticks (`)

Comment: I actually wanted to know how to write stored procedure in nodejs.

Comment: RETURNING would make more sense, just the new records and not all records.